# Center my navbar logo

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my navbar to look like this but the navbar-brand will not center with the other text I'm new this site and it won't let me post the css so I will comment it bellow

[NAVBAR EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JudcU.png)

https://jsbin.com/defibenedo/1/edit?html,css,output

```css
.navbar-brand { font-size: 20px; font-family: "STIXGeneral"; color: black; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; } .navbar .navbar-nav { display: inline-block; float: none; vertical-align: top; } .navbar .navbar-collapse { text-align: center; }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "STIXGeneral";
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}

Comment: Create a jsfiddle, jsbin or codepen for it. Otherwise we have no idea what you mean or how to reproduce it

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: Try googling "jsfiddle", "jsbin" or "codepen". They allow you to create a demo version of your html and css. Also yes, you can post CSS into a stack overflow question.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/defibenedo/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: check : https://jsfiddle.net/stalinrajindian/2fuakfpy/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.navbar-brand {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}


/* DEMO example styles for logo image */
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
}
.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 7px 14px;
}
</style>
<h1 class="text-center">Center Navbar Brand / Logo On Mobile Display</h1>
<p class="text-center lead">
  Resize the browser width to view the effect!
</p>


<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://disputebills.com"><img src="http://www.goodmanmfg.com/Portals/0/images/Logos/BBB%20Logo-tall.jpg" alt="Dispute Bills">
      </a>
      </div>



      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

Please check that link : https://codepen.io/bootstrapped/pen/dGPZvR

Answer (score 0):

**A.** One way would be to include your `navbar-brand` as a list item. at the position where you want it to be. And then add `margin` or `padding` left right to create your desired output

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39504/) as in the snippet the navbar is hidden ( mobile screen size )

```css
.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "STIXGeneral";
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 30px;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>

</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">VENDER</a>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**B.** You could also split your menu into two parts ( one `float:left` other `float:right`) but that might cause mobile menu behavior issues.

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39505/) and/or code snippet below

```css
.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "STIXGeneral";
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>

</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

  </ul>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">VENDER</a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What i want to say is that with your current HTML structure, what you want may not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this

```css
.navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    z-index:3;
}
.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

        <div class="navbar-header text-center">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">VENDER</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```